# Aggregate (function = mean) for duplicate sample ID, but keep string columns

Tags: r, aggregate, mean, categorical-data

I would like to average numerical columns for samples that have duplicate sample IDs, without losing string columns.

I have managed to take averages for duplicate sample IDs using the aggregate function, but first I have to remove the non-numerical columns from the dataset to get it to work. I would like to keep these descriptive columns in.

Creating a fake dataset:

```
ID<-c("QYZ","MMM","QYZ","bb2","gm6","gm6","YOU","LLL","LLL","LLL")
values<-c(1,2,4,5,5,6,8,9,6,4)
Levels<-c("A","B","A","C",'D','D',"C","y","y","y")

Exampledata<-data.frame(ID,values,Levels)
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```
Exampledata2<- aggregate(Exampledata[,-3], by = list(Exampledata$ID), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Exampledata2 looks like this after the code:

```
  Group.1 ID   values

    bb2 NA 5.000000
    gm6 NA 5.500000
    LLL NA 6.333333  
    MMM NA 2.000000
    QYZ NA 2.500000
    YOU NA 8.000000
```

But I would like it to look like this:

```
 ID    values    Levels
  MMM      2      B
  QYZ      2.5    A
  bb2      5      C
  gm6      5.5    D
  YOU      8      C
  LLL      6.33   y
```

Note that the Levels are the same between duplicated sample IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  I looks like you need to include levels in your group by statement if you want it to carry forward.

```
aggregate(Exampledata["values"], by = list(ID = ID, Levels = Levels), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Here's the same thing with data.table

```
as.data.table(Exampledata)[, .(values = mean(values)), .(ID, Levels)]
```

Comment: You can also add the `dplyr` example as: `Exampledata %>% group_by(ID, Levels) %>%  summarise(values = mean(values, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I didn't realize you could add extra arguments to the by(list=

Comment: Perhaps `aggregate`'s formula interface is worth mentioning in this context. `aggregate(values ~ ID + Levels, Exampledata, mean)`